# What should I be doing to become a top tier Plutus Developer?(Besides Plutus-Pioneer-Program)

Tags: plutus, development, learning

I want to know everything there is to know about development on Cardano. I am currently following the plutus pioneer program, but would like to dig deeper.

Are there any videos, articles, documents or lectures that some more experienced developers can recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you re-phrase the question to fit in line with the guidelines: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Can I ask what PRs are? I'm new to this programming but also thinking of learning the basics on many programming languages like Python, Javascript, Java, Solidity and Haskell in 4 month. Maybe do Plutus together with Haskell let's see. But I won't be developing, that I will pay developers to do. But at the same time I need the basics to be able to talk to them and we can understand each other 

Comment: Yeah PRs is just short for Pull Requests. They are an integral part of working on a git repository with a team. Heres a little explanation on [Pull Requests](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests)

Comment: Thanks however, I don’t understand those things that well. Haha

This is hypothetical and not what I will do. But it will help with some financial calculations. 

Could anyine give me an estimation of both how many developers to fork cardano and hydra as it looks today and to some twerking in the protocol/code to be more tailored in what a person would prefer?

Also how long it would take for a specific amount of team?

And an estimated price for this? Both total and per developer and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fellow Plutus Pioneer here.
Besides following the lectures closely and doing the homework (potentially several times), I would recommend digging into the actual plutus project, go through the source and find your way around. As you know, [plutus](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus) is currently being developed, so any videos, articles, and documents (even comments in the source code itself) can be outdated rather quickly. So my suggestion is to work with plutus closely. Find some use cases to implement, but also follow the development closely.

See if you can fix some of the issues and/or review the PRs that are made on the GitHub repo and contribute your own.